# Educational resources to accompany Space Exploration

Tags: discussion, resources, education

We have a couple threads containing infographics and a wide array of important books covering the topics we discuss on this site. Let's try to collect educational resources! This can include video lectures, lecture materials, or any free resources of information pertaining to aerospace engineering. It can be tough to find educational resources on these specific topics, but here are a few. Hopefully you can add some as well.

Here is the current list:

[Aircraft Systems Engineering](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-885j-aircraft-systems-engineering-fall-2005/)

[Ascent - Commemorating the Shuttle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2VygftZSCs)

[Engineering Mathematics](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL13760D87FA88691D)

[NASA - Aerodynamics Index](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/airplane/short.html)

[NASA - Propulsion Index](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/airplane/shortp.html)

[NASA - Hypersonic Aerodynamics Index](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/BGH/shorth.html)

[Space Transport and Engineering Methods](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Space_Transport_and_Engineering_Methods)

Comment: Just found this one, and it is a wikibook, so there are people here who would be well-suited to expanding it. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Space_Transport_and_Engineering_Methods Already had a lot of structure and content.

Answer (score 5):

One of the best video lecture series I have come across is the [**Aircraft Systems Engineering**](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-885j-aircraft-systems-engineering-fall-2005/) course from MIT. If you haven't watched these yet, I highly suggest you do. All of the speakers used to be heavily involved with the development of the Space Shuttle Orbiter.

Comment: I just started working through that. It's amazing.

Comment: yeah this is one of my favorites. take notes while watching the videos if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another video from Glenn Research Center showing many different slow-motion camera angles from STS-114, STS-117, and STS-124. The commentators discuss each angle in detail, explaining what is happening in the launch sequence and the purpose of different structures on and around the Shuttle during launch. There is a wealth of information here. [**Ascent - Commemorating the Shuttle**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2VygftZSCs)

Answer (score 2):

There is also a playlist with 11 hours of video in 45 sections on [YouTube called Engineering Mathematics YouTube Workbook](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL13760D87FA88691D), by Dr Chris Tisdell
The Workbook that goes with this course is available on [Bookboon](http://bookboon.com/en/engineering-mathematics-youtube-workbook-ebook) (it is an ad-supported free pdf download)

And the Jet Propulsion Laboratory has a downloadable [video primer](http://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/video/products/MultimediaProductsPresentationsSlides/) on orbital mechanics. It lasts about 90 minutes in 4 parts and is accompanied by a pdf that is a bunch of illustrative charts.